# Deploy multiple projects to same IIS web site

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-deployment

I have a complete solution with multiple projects (repository, services, helpers, etc.) and in particular one executable project WebAPI and another called Web. Ideally I would like to deploy everything to the same IIS website but having the WebAPI using

```
www.mysite.com/api/routes
```

and the *regular* Web (which is a SPA using the API)

```
www.mysite.com/home
```

So both projects have seperate controllers but should be on the same website (but one in a subfolder).

I just don't really know how to setup the IIS. I was trying to create multiple website, but that doesn't work, since I can't set a subfolder (/api). Virtual Directories don't work, since I cannot deploy seperately onto a virtual directory. 
Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with this statement:

> Virtual Directories don't work, since I cannot deploy seperately onto a virtual directory.

When creating a virtual directory you create a path in the main website which points to a webroot. That webroot can (and should be) outside the main websites webroot. This means you can deploy either the SPA or API independently by targeting the aapropriate webroot.

Comment: I made a typo in my deploy settings, just write `mysite/virtualdirectory` and it works. Thanks for pointing that out